# Azure DevOps Pipelines Agent Pool via Terraformed Scale Set

Tags: azure-devops-pipelines, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I was tasked with creating a Linux-based Scale Set for use with Azure DevOps Pipelines in Terraform.

I have everything set up for the basics; however, when I click on the *Agents* tab in the *Agent pools* area of my DevOps Project, I get the message:

> No agents are connected
> Azure virtual machine scale set agents will appear here when they are created.

I assume that I need the agent installed using [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops).

What I have done so far:

1. Terraform my Azure Scale Set using [azurerm_linux_virtual_machine_scale_set](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/linux_virtual_machine_scale_set) - I am using **UbuntuServer 18.04-LTS**
2. Add the [CustomScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-linux) extension via [azurerm_virtual_machine_scale_set_extension](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/virtual_machine_scale_set_extension)
3. Pass in a custom `commandToExecute` parameter read from a file in Terraform
4. In my DevOps project, add a new *Agent pool* that uses the Scale Set created

In my custom script, I have the basic download and unpacking of the Linux agent:

```
mkdir azure-agent
curl -sSL https://vstsagentpackage.azureedge.net/agent/2.187.2/vsts-agent-linux-x64-2.187.2.tar.gz --output vsts-agent.tar.gz
tar -zxf vsts-agent.tar.gz -C azure-agent
```

Per the instructions, I need to run the `config.sh` script, which is interactive.

**My questions are these:**

1. Is there a better way to do this than running the custom script to install the agent?
2. If there is not a better way to do this, how can I get the data that the agent needs into the VMs without running the `config.sh` script?

I looked through the output of `az vm extension image list --output table` and did not see anything in there besides the `Microsoft.Azure.Monitor` set of extensions, which does not seem like what I'd want to use and I didn't see any anything labeled "vsts". Using `az vm image list --all` didn't turn up anything I noticed, either.

**Update 1**

After playing around I was able to find `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.TeamServicesAgentLinux` v1.21, with some basic settings:

```
  settings = jsonencode({
    "isPipelinesAgent"        = true
    "agentFolder"             = "/agent"
    "agentDownloadUrl"        = "https://vstsagentpackage.azureedge.net/agent/2.187.2/vsts-agent-linux-x64-2.187.2.tar.gz"
    "enableScriptDownloadUrl" = "https://vstsagenttools.blob.core.windows.net/tools/ElasticPools/Linux/6/enableagent.sh"
  })
```

This still doesn't give me options for what the `config.sh` script asks for when run.

**Update 2**

I followed the suggestion from @Joy and was able to verify that my script I created runs successfully. Which looks like this and functions just fine if I SSH into a VM and execute it:

```
set -e

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install -y jq apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg lsb-release python3 python3-pip

sudo apt install -y liblttng-ust0 libkrb5-3 zlib1g

sudo apt install -y libssl1.1 || \
  sudo apt install -y libssl1.0.2 || \
  sudo apt install -y libssl1.0.0

sudo apt install -y libicu67 || \
  sudo apt install -y libicu66 || \
  sudo apt install -y libicu63 || \
  sudo apt install -y libicu60 || \
  sudo apt install -y libicu57 || \
  sudo apt install -y libicu55 || \
  sudo apt install -y libicu52

# download the Azure script & run the setup
if [[ -d vsts-install ]]; then
  rm -Rf vsts-install
fi

mkdir vsts-install
cd vsts-install

curl -sSL https://vstsagentpackage.azureedge.net/agent/2.187.2/vsts-agent-linux-x64-2.187.2.tar.gz --output vsts.tgz
tar -zxf vsts.tgz

./config.sh --unattended \
            --url https://dev.azure.com/MyOrganization \
            --auth pat \
            --token "MY_TOKEN" \
            --pool TerraformedDevOpsPool \
            --replace

sudo ./svc.sh install || true
sudo ./svc.sh stop || true
sudo ./svc.sh start
```

The problem is that when I have it set up in my node pool, it is not executing. I am doing that through this Terraform configuration:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_scale_set_extension" "pipeliens_vms_custom_script" {
  name                         = "TestingExtension"
  virtual_machine_scale_set_id = azurerm_linux_virtual_machine_scale_set.pipelines_vms.id
  publisher                    = "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions"
  type                         = "CustomScript"
  type_handler_version         = "2.0"

  settings = jsonencode({
    "commandToExecute" = file(abspath("./scripts/pipelinesVmStartupScript.sh"))
  })
}
```

I just need to figure out how to view the failures from the script or figure out why it's not launching the way I expect it to.

**Update 3**

Switched to this an it runs:

```
resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine_scale_set" "pipelines_vms" {
  ...
  custom_data                     = base64encode(file(abspath("./scripts/pipelinesVmStartupScript.sh")))
```

Just need to figure out why the `config.sh` run is failing.

**Update 4**

Script fails with:

> Must not run with sudo

I am going to create a user in the script and have it run as that user. This should do the trick.

Comment: How about use custom script extension (Windows | Linux) of ARM template and configure the build agent in unattended mode? https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/1714#issuecomment-452982687

Comment: @Joy I didn't see that "unattended" link in there! That might do the trick.

Comment: @Joy that started me on the right path. Now (as I stated in my most recent update) I just need to figure out why my script is failing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So no one else has to go through this pain.

The `custom_data` part works peachy keen.
This is the script I needed to get it running:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install -y jq apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg lsb-release

sudo apt install -y liblttng-ust0 libkrb5-3 zlib1g

sudo apt install -y libssl1.1 || \
  sudo apt install -y libssl1.0.2 || \
  sudo apt install -y libssl1.0.0

sudo apt install -y libicu67 || \
  sudo apt install -y libicu66 || \
  sudo apt install -y libicu63 || \
  sudo apt install -y libicu60 || \
  sudo apt install -y libicu57 || \
  sudo apt install -y libicu55 || \
  sudo apt install -y libicu52

sudo addgroup vsts
sudo useradd -s /bin/bash -d /home/vsts -m -g vsts vsts
sudo usermod -aG sudo vsts

sudo mkdir /vsts-install
cd /vsts-install

sudo curl -sSL https://vstsagentpackage.azureedge.net/agent/2.187.2/vsts-agent-linux-x64-2.187.2.tar.gz --output vsts.tgz
sudo tar -zxf vsts.tgz
sudo chown -R vsts:vsts /vsts-install

sudo su -c "./config.sh --unattended --url https://dev.azure.com/${MY_ORGANIZATION} --auth pat --token ${MY_INJECTED_TOKEN} --pool ${MY_POOL_NAME} --replace 2>&1 | tee /tmp/CONFIG_LOG" vsts

sudo ./svc.sh install || true
sudo ./svc.sh stop || true
sudo ./svc.sh start

cd ..
```